# Is there is any alternative for spring OncePerRequestFilter in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

Currently we are migrating spring application to Quarkus, In my spring application Authentication filter is using
(Which extendsorg.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter)  . In Quarkus how I can use this filter. Could you please help on this?

Regards,
Abel

Comment: Quarkus does not have anything like that. What is the use case you need to implement?

Comment: @geoand    In our scenario, all the requests are initially pass through the filter and validate the session there and redirect the response .

Comment: But why that specific filter?

Comment: In old code I can see multiple filter, but the use case,only i understood that mentioned the previous comment. In  Quarkus, if we have same use case we can use any other filter?

Comment: As I said, we don't have some analogous, but I still don't understand why that filter is useful